# tcolorbox and svg package shadow error/bug

Tags: tcolorbox, svg

There's a bug with the shadows of tcolorboxes when using tcolorbox and svg packages together.

Top is with svg package **not** loaded while bottom one is with svg package loaded.
[image]

Here's a mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
%\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,drop fuzzy shadow]
Text
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Any suggestions/ideas/workarounds?

Comment: I don't think this a bug, but rather a different transparency or color setting after svg is loaded

Comment: The 'culprit` is apparently the `transparent` package which is loaded by `svg`. If `\usepackage{transparent}` is used (instead of `svg`) the same effect occurs

Comment: That's interessting. Thank you. Any ideas on what to do about it? Loading tcolorbox after the svg package does not help.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea at the moment

Comment: Using the `transparent` package stops the `tikz` option `fill opacity` from working (this is used by `tcolorbox`). I have no idea how to change that.

Comment: Any news here? Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not. My workaround was to use pdf images and not straight svgs..